# Should i pass session variables through an ajax function or access it directly in the script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that uses an ajax function to get updates from another page.The function uses the user's id, which is retrieved from a session variable to find any updates, which is then displayed in a "Updates" div. While my script is working currently, i find myself wondering if i could retrieve the userid stored in the session variable in my Ajax page instead of passing the userid through the ajax function. **Are there any advantages and/or disadvantages to passing the userid through the ajax function instead of accessing it directly in the ajax script?**

My Ajax function:

```
function FetchUpdate()
{
    var userid= <?php echo $_SESSION['UserID'] ?>;
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"getupdates.php",
        data:{userid:userid}
    })

    .done(function(data){
        $("#Updates").html(data);
        setTimeout(FetchUpdate,1000*60);

    })

}
```

Ajax page(getupdates.php)

```
session_start();
$userid=$_SESSION['UserID'];
//fetches updates
//echos updates
```

Comment: You don't have to pass the userID at all. PHP already have it. Maybe `data:{userid:userid}` can be replaced with some command like `data:{command:'getUpdate'}'`, and PHP will get the userID from its session variables, and if there's no userID session, php will pass an error and javascript will handle the error on client side.

Comment: In PHP, you should handle the post object like; `$command = $_POST['command']` and check if `$command == 'getUpdates'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example approach of your situation:

**Javascript :**

```
function fetchUpdate(){
    var data = {}
        data.command = 'getUpdate'
    $.post('getupdates.php', data, function(result){
        var r = JSON.parse(result)
        try {
            if(r.status == true){
                console.log('Success! '+r.message)
            }else{
                console.log(r.message)
            }
        }catch(e){
            console.log(result)
        }
    })
}
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){$session = new Session();}
$uid = isset($_SESSION['userID']) ? $_SESSION['userID'] : 0;

if(isset($_POST['command'])){$cmd = $_POST['command']}

switch($cmd){
    case 'getUpdate':
    // Check $uid with database here.
        if($uid > 0){
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'User details have been updated.';
        }else{
            $response['status'] = false
            $response['message'] = 'Invalid user.'
        }
    break;
    // Process other commands here.
}
// Return output
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any difference to using new Session() instead of session_start? i can't seem to find anything about new session() on google.

Comment: That new session is only to check whether the session has started or not, and if not, I put session in new variable. You should put `session_start()` at the topmost of the php.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to retrieve the userid stored in the session variable in the Ajax page.

In case you send `UserId`s through ajax, someone could brute-force generate them and get other people private data. Note this is only an advantage if your `UserId`s are easier to guess than SESSID.

Moreover, you avoid sending unnecessary data.

Answer (score 0):

If you identify the user via the userid passed in POST, one could do an HTTP request to your AJAX script passing a falsified userid.

I think it's better to access the userid via the `$_SESSION['UserID']`.

By the way, in `getupdates.php` I can't see where you access `$_POST['userid']` passed in the AJAX request (`data:{userid:userid}`)...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it on the front-end, that is unsafe as Andrea Riva said.

I think you can store it in case session miss.

I wouldn't suggest you make sending userid via ajax.